Rigify only making half of the controls
I'm trying to generate a rig with rigify as i've done many times before but for some reason it only produces one side of the rig. My model is not perfectly simmetrical but it's close enough that i decided to delete one side and symmetrize and then manually line up any bones not in the correct place. All bones are named correctly as it was mirrored but it does not produce any arm or leg controls for the mirrored side. Is there any fix without having to redo everything? Thank you


If you symmetrized the model, why not do the same for the armature? That way you should get both aligning automatically and all the bone names should be correct.

Sorry I symmetrized the bones in the armature not the model, I was a bit unclear in my description. I saw something about enabling python scripting in other posts but I can't seem to find anything related to that. It's just very weird it isn't working. I can provide the file if necessary

I solved it, the rig types are set in the Metarig in Pose Mode in the Bone tab. I just copied the settings of the side that worked. The symmetrized bones did not have any groups and it generated properly i think

I solved it. The rig types are set in the Metarig in Pose Mode in the Bone tab. I copied the settings from the side that worked. The symmetrized bones did not have any groups, but it generated properly, I think.
